# What role does Node.js play in MEAN stack between JavaScript and Express compared to Django and Python?

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, express, mean-stack

I have background in implementing web applications using Python and its popular framework Django and PostgreSQL. Recently I've shifted my attention from Python to JavaScript and planned to take advantage of the benefits that MEAN stack has to offer.

In terms of backend structure, I understand MongoDB is the database to MEAN just like PostgreSQL (and other relational database) is to Python. Express is the framework just like Django. However, where does Node.js fit into? What does it do? What's the equivalent of Node.js in a Django structure? Why does Django+Python combination not need this "extra" layer of abstraction? What feature(s) do JavaScript lack that it needs this extra layer?

I know it might be a simple question but I'm having a hard time understanding it! Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that "Javascript" is not in the acronym, whereas with something like LAMP, Python (or PHP or whichever) is. In MEAN, Node.js takes the place of Javascript.

Node.js is basically an interpreter and a runtime environment for Javascript. It is used in the acronym rather than Javascript to distinguish it as separate from browser Javascript. Plus, MEAJ is a pretty horrible acronym.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! The official documentation says that NodeJS incorporates Chrome's V8 engine at its core. Since V8 acts as the interpreter/compiler, I guess Node.js is the runtime environment? What exactly is a runtime environment, if you don't mind explain a bit more? Thank you!

Comment: Basically -- the environment in which the language operates. To highlight a difference: JS in the browser stores many of its global variables in the `window` object. Node.js, on the other hand, holds its set of global variables in the `process` object. Try typing `window` in the browser js console and `process` in the node.js command line for a closer look.

Comment: Slight mistake -- `global` is the global object in Node.js. `process` is an object within the global object.

Answer (score 0):

Node is the interpreter/environment. It's literally the thing that is executing your JavaScript code. I think a better comparison is to think about how the JVM relates to Java

Comment: Hi Steve! Thank you for your quick response. To my understanding, doesn't the MEAN backend run on Google's V8 JavaScript engine? In this sense, V8 is interpreter?

Comment: Node.js is a C implementation of the Google V8 JavaScript engine. I understand this to mean that Google V8 Javascript engine is the interface to which Node.js adheres to.